# Triggering Fancybox in dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog, fancybox

My `<a>` tag which has the call for the Fancybox function will load after calling from ajax. Upon clicking on the link, the modal window wont show up. I tried using the `<a>` in a static way and it works, but not through dynamic code. I also noticed that upon viewing "Source" in my ie browser, the tag is not present. Any help? Thanks!!

this code will be created dynamically after calling ajax from the server side (I'm using java). Im using class as my link to the jquery function because the tags can be several instances with the same class name:

```
 <a class="link" href="#task" title="Details">View details</a>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="task" style="width:400px;height:100px;overflow:auto;">
            some data from the server.
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my fancybox function:

```
$("a.link").fancybox({
        'titlePosition' : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none'
});
```

Comment: some code would be helpful for potential answerers :)

Answer (score 3):

fancyBox starting from v2.0 uses "live" to bind click event, so it will work for dynamically created elements, too.

Comment: That won't work if you're force to use Fancybox 1 due to a plugin such as https://github.com/moskis/fancybox-for-wordpress, or of the like.

Answer (score 2):

When you dynamic add new elements to DOM after document is ready, fancybox is unable to "bind" those new elements, instead you can try to listen for events on those elements with delegate() and then dynamically create a infobox like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p { background:yellow; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; 
      padding:5px; }
    p.over { background: #ccc; }
    span { color:red; }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pcapr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r75/trunk/script/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("body").delegate("#example7", "click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox({
                //'modal': false,
                //'padding'        : 0,
                'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut'    : 'fade',
                'titlePosition': 'inside',
                'autoDimensions': false,
                'title': this.title,
                'width': 400,
                'height': 400,
                'href': this.href,
                'margin': 5,
                'showCloseButton': true,
                'autoScale':true,
                'hideOnOverlayClick':true,
                'hideOnContentClick':true,
                'overlayShow': true
                //'type': 'iframe'
            }

            );

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><a title="Cras neque mi, semper at interdum id, dapibus in leo. Suspendisse nunc leo, eleifend sit amet iaculis et, cursus sed turpis." href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_167-sL7Cczk/TBiMz6jdtYI/AAAAAAAABcs/JxqC2vCIFa4/s1600/cute-puppy-dog-wallpapers.jpg" id="example7">hola, click me for fancybox</a></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

At least it worked for me! good luck!

Comment: the code doesn't work for galleries though... It opens the first image no problem, but when you try to switch to the next/prev, it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use [**livequery**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery().live('mouseenter') to allow fancybox to attach to dynamic content.

```
jQuery("a.fancybox").live('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Make sure NOT to use `jQuery(this).fancybox();` or else it will only look for the items inside "mouseenter", which will more than likely only be one image and break galleries.